# Clever way to create stack of conditions in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, logic, structure

Im developing **Ticketing website (PHP+MySql)** where present many user types like `user`,`manager`,`ceo` etc... and here i have on logical problem

when ticket is being viewed by some user under ticket form displayed  buttons amount can be different based on different conditions like: user type, ticket status or if  ticket approved by manager etc ..

so my **question** is how i can create some logical structure in php that can handle that multiple conditions and modify them easily in future (add new condition, delete old)

my **aim** is to not hardcore it php many ifs like `if(A=B && C=D ...){ /*show confirm button*/ }`

my current **idia** to crate php files named `user_actions.php`, `manager_actions.php`, ... write inside this many `ifs` conditions according to its role type and include it under ticket form `include $user['type']_actions.php` but this will just separate that many stupid ifs in different files

So please, can anyone suggest better way how to create more clever logic for this ? just simple description in few words no need bring big code snippet examples

PS: i know that this is not so appropriate question type for **stackoverflow** but anyway it is **logical issue** and i'm looking for clever solution

Comment: Access control, roles and permission based systems are hard.  Here is a pointer: http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/

Comment: @Progrock thank you for that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you'll have to write down all those conditions. I would create a central user class and put all those conditions right into it.

```
class User {
    public function __construct($wearsTie, $looksAngry, $alktsAlot) {
        $this->wearsTie = $waersTie;
        $this->looksAngry = $looksAngry;
        $this->talksAlot = $talksAlot;
    }

    public function isManager() {
        return ($this->wearsTie && $this->looksAngry)
    }

    public function isCEO() {
        return ($this->wearsTie && $this->talksAlot);
    }
}
```

In your view you could than simply use

```
$user = new User(true,true,false);

if($user->isCEO) {
    echo "I'm CEO!";
} else {
    echo "I whish I was CEO :-(";
}
```

Of corse the properties of the user class have to adjusted to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, seems i'm going to create this logic based on your suggestion but a bit in other way  but anyway i'm accepting your answer as resolving one for my question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [switch blocks](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
switch($user_type){
    case('ceo'):
        // do stuff for CEO
    break;
    case('manager'):
        // do stuff for manager
    break;
    case('user'):
        // do stuff for users
    break;
    default:
        // do stuff fo everyone else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following principle:

Create a database table `user_level` with user levels (user, manager, etc).

Create a database table `conditions` with conditions. Each condition is linked tot the `user_level` table. This allows you to easily add/edit/remove conditions.

In the code you can create queries that fetch conditions for certain user levels. Then loop through all the results and check if the conditions are met. This way your code is flexible and not hardcoded full of IF-statements

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion